# Get list of recent searches with REST API

Tags: rest

Is it possible to get list of recent searches? I mean "search salesforce" input box at top.

Comment: Are you looking for something around this -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_search_scope_order.htm

Comment: nope, I need user's inputs in search box